# Cannot trigger next function when previous completed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a chain reaction by executing next function after executing previous one. Code looks like this:

```
var med = {

    imgLoadTime : 2000,

    easingEffect : 'easeOutQuart',

    scrollEase : 'easeInOutQuad',

    effectDuration : 1000,

    currentPage : '',

    runAnimations : function(){
                        if(this.currentPage == '#slide5'){
                            this.initAssets();
                        }
                    },

    initAssets : function(){
                    $('#asset-1').animate(
                        {left : '50%'}, 
                        { 
                            duration: this.effectDuration, 
                            easing: this.easingEffect, 
                            complete: this.assetTwo 
                        });
                },

    assetTwo : function(){
                    console.log('two');
                    debugger;
                    $('#asset-2').animate(
                        {left : '50%'}, 
                        { 
                            duration: this.effectDuration, 
                            easing: this.easingEffect, 
                            complete: this.assetThree 
                        });
                },

    assetThree : function(){
                    console.log('three');
                    $('#asset-3').animate(
                        {left : '50%'}, 
                        {
                            duration: this.effectDuration, 
                            easing: this.easingEffect, 
                            complete: console.log('weszlo')
                        });
                }

};
```

This is how my object looks like. Then I run function runAnimations as a property of object. What is weird that during this chain only assetTwo function executes, but no further (assetThree). Why so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this type of definition:

```
complete: this.assetTwo
```

It will call assetTwo, but it won't have the right `this` value.  Instead, you need to do this:

```
           initAssets : function(){
                var self = this;
                $('#asset-1').animate(
                    {left : '50%'}, 
                    { 
                        duration: this.effectDuration, 
                        easing: this.easingEffect, 
                        complete: function() {self.assetTwo()}
                    });
            },
```

Same for the other complete functions.  You need to save the value of `this` into a local variable and then use it in the complete function to invoke the next method.  This will make sure that `this` is set properly for the next method.

Comment: +1 - beat me to it. Another case of `self = this`! :) The reason `self = this` works is because the parent whose `this` the OP thought they were targeting will still retain the scope of `self` inside of the child functions.

Comment: @lesny09 - The value of `this` is set by the caller.  In the animation complete function, `this` is probably set to the object that was being animated.  Thus, in your original code when the complete occurs and `assetTwo()` was called, `this` would not be set to your object, but to the `#asset-1` being animated.  This would mess up the next item in the animation because `this.assetThree()` would not exist because it was the wrong `this`.  Since it doesn't exist, it would stop the sequence.  Saving the right value into a local variable and using that one guarantees that it gets the right `this`.

Comment: javascript is confusing me when it comes to scope issues. thank for clarifying this, though!

Comment: @lesny09 - just remember that `this` is controlled by the caller and that helps a lot, not by how you pass the function reference.

Answer (score 1):

Your this changes with each function, you could reference it by `med` instead to get the desired result:

```
assetTwo : function(){

                //debugger;
                $('#asset-2').animate(
                    {left : '50%'}, 
                    { 
                        duration: med.effectDuration, 
                        easing: med.easingEffect, 
                        complete: med.assetThree 
                    });
            },
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/johnkoer/2KHnc/16/

Answer (score 0):

use med instead of `this` at all places in you javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

For nice tight code use a jQuery `$.Deferred.pipe()` chain as described **[here](http://onwebdev.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/jquery-deferred-objects-and-sequential.html)**

You should end up with something like this :

```
var med = {
    imgLoadTime: 2000,
    currentPage: '',
    css : {left: '50%'},
    animOptions: {
        duration: 1000, 
        easing: 'easeOutQuart'
    };
    runAnimations: function() {
        if(med.currentPage == '#slide5') {
            $.Deferred(function(dfr) {
                dfr.pipe(function() {
                    return $('#asset-1').animate( med.css, med.animOptions );
                }).pipe(function() {
                    return $('#asset-2').animate( med.css, med.animOptions );
                }).pipe(function() {
                    return $('#asset-3').animate( med.css, med.animOptions );
                })
            }).resolve();
        }
    }
};
```

*untested*

Get the hang of Deferreds and you'll never look back.

Unless the `med` object is important for other reasons, then it would be simpler just to have `runAnimations()` rather than an object wrapper :

```
function runAnimations() {
    var imgLoadTime = 2000,
    currentPage = '',
    css = {left: '50%'},
    animOptions = {
        duration: 1000, 
        easing: 'easeOutQuart'
    };
    if(currentPage == '#slide5') {
            $.Deferred(function(dfr) {
                dfr.pipe(function() {
                    return $('#asset-1').animate( css, animOptions );
                }).pipe(function() {
                    return $('#asset-2').animate( css, animOptions );
                }).pipe(function() {
                    return $('#asset-3').animate( css, animOptions );
                })
            }).resolve();
    }
}
```

This way references to the fixed parameters are straightforward.